# std::shared_ptr assignment of data vs. memcpy

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I am using std::shared_ptr in C++11 and I would like to understand if it's better to assign structures of type T in this way:

```
T a_data;
std::shared_ptr<T> my_pointer(new T);
*my_pointer = a_data;
```

or like:

```
memcpy(&my_pointer, data, sizeof(T));
```

or like:

```
my_pointer.reset(a_data);
```

Regards

Mike

Comment: PS. I am translating legacy C code which uses pointers and memcpy/free/malloc like it is raining. I'd like to reduce this amount of operations with shared_ptr

Comment: `memcpy` does not provide the functionality you are looking for. Avoid it. And only one of other two compiles.

Comment: at the moment, all 3 of them compile. But I cannot still test them.

Comment: @blackibiza If they compile, `T` has quite peculiar properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They each do a different thing.

1.

```
T a_data;
std::shared_ptr<T> my_pointer(new T);
*my_pointer = a_data;
```

Here, a new object (call it `n`) of type `T` will be allocated, managed by `my_pointer`. Then, object `a_data` will be copy-assigned into `n`.

2.

```
memcpy(&my_pointer, a_data, sizeof(T));  // I assume you meant a_data here, not data
```

That's total nonsense - tha's overwriting the `shared_ptr` *itself* with the contents of `a_data`. Undefined behaviour at its finest (expect a crash or memory corruption).

Perhaps you actually meant `my_pointer.get()` instead of `&my_pointer` (that is, you wanted to copy into the object being pointed to)? If that's the case, it can work, as long as `T` is *trivially copyable* - which means that it doesn't have non-trivial copy or move ctors, doesn't have non-trivial copy or move assignment operators, and has a trivial destructor. But why rely on that, when normal assignment (`*my_pointer = a_data;`) does exactly the same for that case, and *also* works for non-trivially-copyable classes?

3.

```
my_pointer.reset(a_data);
```

This normally won't compile as-is, it would need to be `my_pointer.reset(&a_data);`. That's disaster waiting to happen - you point `my_pointer` to the automatic (= local) variable `a_data` and give it ownership of that. Which means that when `my_pointer` goes out of scope (actually, when the last pointer sharing ownership wiht it does), it will call the deleter, which normally calls `delete`. On `a_data`, which was not allocated with `new`. Welcome to UB land again!

---

If you just need to manage a dynamically-allocated copy of `a_data` with a `shared_ptr`, do this:

```
T a_data;
std::shared_ptr<T> my_pointer(new T(a_data));
```

Or even better:

```
T a_data;
auto my_pointer = std::make_shared<T>(a_data);
```

Comment: ok thank you! Is it still valid for structures of type T which contains inside other shared_ptr to other structures? (yeah, this C old code I've got it's a nightmare)

Comment: @blackibiza My two solution will work just fine (performing a *shallow* copy). It seems you should look up more on how copying and assignment work in C++; perhaps grab a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465)?

Comment: i know how the assignment work in C++. I had doubts only because of smart pointers, which I've never used before.

Comment: @blackibiza Well, a smart pointer is a class like any other, and its copy and assignment operations are [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). So if you understand copy & assignment, these docs should cover the topic for you.